# Xcode 5.1.1 shell script invocation error

Tags: ios, xcode

As I try to run the app the error comes up with:Print:

> Entry, ":CFBundleShortVersionString", Does Not Exist Parse Error:
>   Unclosed Quotes Value Required for Set Command Command /bin/sh failed
>   with exit code 1

This is the coding for that part in my app

```
#!/bin/sh
VERSION=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :CFBundleShortVersionString' Translator/Translator-Info.plist`
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :PreferenceSpecifiers:0:DefaultValue $VERSION" Translator/Settings.bundle/Root.plist
```

I don't know what's wrong!!

Answer (score 1):

It means in your info.plist file, "Bundle versions string, short" key/value is not present. Add it to info.plist and re compile it.

Comment: What kind of key/value would be suitable? thank you for answering my question

Comment: Open your Translator-Info.plist file and add above key with proper value like 1.0

Comment: tried to add the value 1.0 but is still coming up with the same error